# How can I change Okular's GUI so I get white text on black background or similar, instead of blending colors?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, 21.04, okular

Okular has an odd choice of font and background colors in some places and this makes it difficult to read some text.

I looked at the settings and searched online but couldn't find anything on changing this.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want to change the black theme in Okular?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi No. I want text like "Zoom Out" and "Show sidebar" to use a color that is the opposite of the background they are in so they are easier to read. E.g.: White.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to change the theme for Qt apps.

This can be achieved in two ways, with `qt5ct` and `kvantum` (don't use both of them together).

### Kvantum

Install Kvantum with

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-kvantum
```

Now make KVantum as the default theme manager for Qt apps.

```
echo "export QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=kvantum" >> ~/.profile
```

Reboot.

Now open Kvantum Manager, and apply a suitable theme.
[image]

### Qt5ct

Install qt5ct with

```
sudo apt install qt5ct
```

In Ubuntu 22.04, you will also have to install `qt5-style-plugins`

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins
```

Now make qt5ct the default theme manager for Qt apps.

```
echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="qt5ct"" >> ~/.profile
```

Reboot.

Now open qt5ct and choose style `gtk2`.
[image]

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much for writing this up and making it detailed and friendly.