# Okular change the color of bottom bar

Tags: okular

I can make the bottom bar (the bar that shows page number) of okular disappear by adding the below line under [Main View] of okularpartrc (found in ~/.config).

```
ShowBottomBar=false
```

However, I am interested in changing the color of the bottom bar. I mean I wanna change the color of toolbar and menubar of okular which are all white by default. How can I do that? I tried adding `BottomBarColor=255,0,0` under [Main View] but it doesn't change the color.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Which desktop environment? Can you post a screenshot? Such information might help other users. Right now, it is unclear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Archisman I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in a thinkpad. The toolbar and menubar color in okular are all white by default and the settings don't provide any relevant options to change them. So I had to find a way to change the menubar and toolbar color and I did it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change Okular's GUI so I get white text on black background or similar, instead of blending colors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354831/how-can-i-change-okulars-gui-so-i-get-white-text-on-black-background-or-similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it adding `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2` in /usr/environment. It follows the system theme for QT applications. To change system theme, I had to install gnome-tweaks.

EDIT: It needs a restart to take effect.