# Okular toolbar doesn't change according to gnome theme_22.04

Tags: gnome, pdf, 22.04, okular

Installed Okular on 22.04 a couple of days back and after some tweaking realized that the toolbar doesn't change according to gnome's theme and I can't find the theme option within Okular for the toolbar.

And one side question for Okular users who changed the color mode; does anybody know the color code used on dark reader extension on firefox, I'm trying to match it on Okular but seems a little off with 29282d and 727272. Or any recommended color code that is easy to the eyes.

Kindly advise

[image]

Comment: Okular is a Qt app, and is not affected by the GNOME theme. Please follow this answer to change theme in Okular. https://askubuntu.com/a/1356691/124466

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi, thank you for the reply. Between Kvantum and qt5ct which is more compatible with 22.04 that you'd recommend?

Comment: I have not started using 22.04 yet. I personally use qt5ct on 20.04

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, thank you, qt5ct works smoothly with 22.04 and its light weight which fixed my needs.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, i reinstall a fresh boot and i can't seem to get the original solution to work. The Style selections only has Fusion and Windows now for qt5c. Kindly advise.

Comment: Can you ask a new question about this issue in qt5ct? I have not upgraded to 22.04 yet. Meanwhile, you can try KVantum.