# Some Parts of Ubuntu Still in Light Mode After Switching to Dark Mode

Tags: gnome-shell, 22.04, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweaks

I use Ubuntu 22.04 and installed Gnome Extensions to try to get a purple theme, which that mostly worked out. The problem now is, there are multiple things that are in light mode, such as the Calendar, the Search bar, and others.

The settings I have on normal Ubuntu are on Dark Mode, and the shell theme I have is supposed to make things purple, so I don't understand where the light mode stuff is coming from.

How do I fix this?

Comment: it's probably either due to the new feature in 22.04 where there is separate keys to set up dark and light mode, which you can read from vanadium [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403952/wallpaper-background-switches-back-to-default-when-in-dark-mode-22-04-lts)  or the app you are having problem are not effected by Gnome theme, which you can read from  Archisman Panigrahi's  [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407005/okular-toolbar-doesnt-change-according-to-gnome-theme-22-04). One last possibility is that the extensions you installed are still not 100% with 22.04.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon None of the options seem to have fixed my issue, but thanks for giving me stuff to try. I agree it might be an issue of the theme I have not being supported, or maybe the theme itself makes it have light mode features. I'll see what I can do to fix it.