# GTK Style selection not available in qt5ct after re-installation 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, qt5, okular

As per @Archisman Panigrahi advice, I'm posting a new question regarding `qt5ct`. I've recently reinstall 22.04 and found that the Style drop-down menu only has Fusion and Windows, hence, I am unable to have Okular toolbar change according to Gnome's theme as I did before the re-installation. Weird thing is GTK is available in Standard Dialog drop-down menu.

The original solution is available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354831/how-can-i-change-okulars-gui-so-i-get-white-text-on-black-background-or-similar/1356691#1356691) and my original [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407005/okular-toolbar-doesnt-change-according-to-gnome-theme-22-04?noredirect=1#comment2458464_1407005).

Kindly advise

Comment: I use kvantum, not qt5ct, so I'm not sure, but probably you need to install qt5ct styles provided by the package `qt5-style-plugins`

Comment: @Lorenz Keel, sorry for the late reply, had some troubleshooting with the installations. installing the plugins works, however, I kept getting frequent error messages even though it was working fine. Hence, i decided to use kvantum for now. Thanks

Comment: @LorenzKeel I verified that it works. Can you write that as an answer?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi: done, even though you already published a very good quality answer in the link referenced in this question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Additional styles are available after installing the package `qt5-style-plugins`.

It is available from the Ubuntu repositories and you can install it by:

```
sudo apt install qt5-style-plugins
```

In order to make `qt5ct` the default theme manager for Qt apps, run the command:

```
echo "export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct" >> ~/.profile
```