# How to get dark mode for Scribus?

Tags: 20.04, lts, scribus

Running `Scribus 1.5.8` on `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`. Scribus is installed using `apt`.

As you can see below, for some reason I have no dark mode/theme option. This is my laptop; weirdly enough, on my desktop at home I'm using same Scribus/Ubuntu versions but I do have dark mode there.

I don't remember doing anything special than just activating it on the desktop. Main difference between the two systems might be Laptop=Intel, Desktop=AMD.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to what it might be?

[image]

Comment: Try the Qt5ct method as described here. https://askubuntu.com/a/1356691/124466