# how to configure kde window decorations to dark from ubuntu gnome?

Tags: gnome, themes, plasma, window-decoration

When using KDE applications on ubuntu gnome, these apps don't follow gnome's dark theme, so they remain bright and ugly. However, When running systemsettings and switching between dark and light, I realize it does have an effect on KDE applications like Dolphin, but it isn't ocmplete, it doesn't look the same way it would in a KDE Plasma session. The window decorations remain ugly/light. Moreover, the text remains black on a dark backround (the folder pane). How do I configure things correctly? I want the text to be light on a dark background, and all the window decorations to be dark.

Comment: Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1356691/124466) answer. You can use Yaru theme with Kvantum

Comment: thx that suffices as a workaround. I just wish there were a more official way to do this. Linux came out in 1992. It's been 31 years since then. I can think of so many open-source projects that are just wasted time, yet nobody ever thought hey, maybe it's far more important to concentrate our efforts so someone using both gnome & kde apps (ie almost everybody) to be able to theme them uniformly from a single menu, both on ubuntu and on kubuntu.

Comment: There are official ways to theme gnome apps on KDE, but there is no official ways to theme KDE apps in GNOME. Some distros like Linux Mint applies this fix in the default installation. Ubuntu probably does not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change Okular's GUI so I get white text on black background or similar, instead of blending colors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354831/how-can-i-change-okulars-gui-so-i-get-white-text-on-black-background-or-similar)