# QT apps like Kdenlive have a KDE Plasma style title bar (window decorations) on Gnome

Tags: gnome, window-manager, titlebar, window-decoration

Can anyone explain why some QT apps like qBittorrent,OBS Studio and Kdenlive have a KDE Plasma style title bar and window decorations on my Gnome desktop ?

I have tried various methods for styling qt apps, mainly kvantum and qt5ct. These methods work. They change the application theme. But, the window decorations are stuck as the KDE style.

This issue is only visible on wayland. On X11 this is not an issue.
I've just switched to X11.

1. Image of [QT apps with KDE style Window decorations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41HK4.png)
2. Image of [My System Window decorations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTpft.png)

Comment: This might answer your question https://askubuntu.com/a/1356691/124466

Answer (score 0):

Changing my system to use X11(Xorg) instead of Wayland solved it for me.

Comment: Could you explain how you did that?  It can be useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

Qt apps are styled differently and some Gtk based desktops do not offer any settings for it by default.

Take a look at https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Uniform_look_for_Qt_and_GTK_applications

There's also this one for window decorations on wayland https://github.com/FedoraQt/QAdwaitaDecorations

I personally pair that with https://github.com/GabePoel/KvLibadwaita and now Qt apps look a lot better with GNOME's theme.