# QT Applications Not Adhering to GTK Theme After Upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: themes, gtk, qt

Hello Ubuntu community,

I recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.10 and encountered an issue with QT applications. Despite installing Kvantum and attempting to change the theme, these applications refuse to follow the GTK theme. The discrepancies extend to the mouse cursor, toolbar, and buttons, making them appear inconsistent with other applications.

I'm seeking assistance to resolve this matter. Has anyone else experienced similar problems after upgrading to Ubuntu 23.10? Any guidance on how to ensure consistent theming for QT applications would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you configure kvantum as described here https://askubuntu.com/a/1356691/124466 ?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes!

Comment: Qt and GTK theming differ, you need to set both to use *equivalent* rather than *contrasting* themes in your selection. GTK theming impacts GTK apps only.  Most QA for *release-upgrades* is all paths (ie. 22.04 to 22.10, 23.04 then 23.10) or LTS to LTS. Your chosen upgrade path is CI testing mostly (not end-user QA tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're facing theme inconsistencies with QT applications after installing Kvantum or Qt5ct on Ubuntu 23.10, there's a straightforward solution. Set the following environment variable to enhance compatibility:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb
```

This adjustment ensures a smoother integration of QT applications with the chosen themes. After installation, you should observe improved theming consistency across your system.

Comment: This is only a partial solution on my system... Icons and mouse cursor are inherited, but not the widgets.