How to enable Dark Mode on VirtualBox 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04?
The Subject pretty much sums it up. I'm trying to figure out how to enable Dark Mode on VirtualBox 7.0 on a Ubuntu 22.04 host. On a Windows host, if you go into Preferences, there is an Interface selection in the left-hand column, and you go there to enable Dark Mode, but in Linux host, the Interface item is not in the Preferences menu.
Is there some other way to enable Dark Mode?

Virtualbox is a Qt app. First choose the dark mode for the rest of the system using System Settings. Install and enable qt5ct as described in this answer, which is valid for any qt app https://askubuntu.com/a/1356691/124466.

Worked like a charm!  Thanks!  If you want to post this as an answer, I'll upvote and accept it as correct.  Thanks again!

You can just upvote the other answer and mark this as duplicate :)
